# How to get a snapshot of a WPF element in varying sizes without affecting the Quality of Curves and Text rendered?

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, graphics, charts, rendering

I am working on a chart control in WPF.
I need to implement a functionality to take a snapshot of Chart in any input size without affecting the quality of Curves and Texts rendered on it.

The functionality is already implemented, but now problem is, while taking the snapshot using FrameworkElement.Transform() screen flickers as the actual control is getting resized and re-rendered.

Can anyone suggest me a solution or a pointer to work on to eliminate the problem. One important thing to mention is the data to be rendered on Chart is huge due to which it takes some time to re-render the data on Chart.

Any kind of help is much appreciated.